# Use WebBrowser control in page instead of popup for Identity Server 4 login

Tags: wpf, mvvm, webbrowser-control, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication on my WPF MVVM app. Currently, when the user wants to log in, a popup window appears with the login screen and the info gets passed back through the OidcClientOptions. However, instead of a popup window, I want the login page to show up on a WebBrowser control in the actual application. How can I accomplish this?

My Login code:

```
public class Login
{
    private OidcClient _oidcClient = null;
    LoginResult result = null;
    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();

    public async void LoginPage()
    {
        var options = new OidcClientOptions()
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:5001/",
            ClientId = "wpf",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "openid WebAPI",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost/signin-oidc",
            Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
            Browser = new WpfEmbeddedBrowser();
        };

        _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);

        try
        {
            result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (result.IsError)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            accessToken.WriteToken(result.AccessToken);
            App.Current.Properties["AccessToken"] = result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Current WpfEmbeddedBrowser I'm using:

```
public class WpfEmbeddedBrowser : IBrowser
    {
        private BrowserOptions _options = null;

        public WpfEmbeddedBrowser()
        {

        }

        public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            _options = options;

            var window = new Window()
            {
                Width = 900,
                Height = 625,
                Title = "IdentityServer Login"
            };

            // Note: Unfortunately, WebBrowser is very limited and does not give sufficient information for 
            //   robust error handling. The alternative is to use a system browser or third party embedded
            //   library (which tend to balloon the size of your application and are complicated).
            var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

            var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

            var result = new BrowserResult()
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
            };

            webBrowser.Navigating += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (BrowserIsNavigatingToRedirectUri(e.Uri))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;

                    result = new BrowserResult()
                    {
                        ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                        Response = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri
                    };

                    signal.Release();

                    window.Close();
                }
            };

            window.Closing += (s, e) =>
            {
                signal.Release();
            };

            window.Content = webBrowser;
            window.Show();
            webBrowser.Source = new Uri(_options.StartUrl);

            await signal.WaitAsync();

            return result;
        }

        private bool BrowserIsNavigatingToRedirectUri(Uri uri)
        {
            return uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_options.EndUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you eventually found the way to accomplish that?

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich no, sorry. I ended up settling for the popup window.